# What is wrong with my python recursive quick sort algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, recursion, quicksort

So my algorithm has two functions. The first is `partition` which takes the first element of the list as the pivot and places all elements larger than it after it and all the smallest before it and I have tested it and it works just fine. The second function `quicksort` function and it uses `partition` recursively to sort the entire list. When I run the code in pycharm it says maximum recursion depth exceeded and a few other errors. Here is the code:

```
arr = [81, 4, 73, 1, 98, 69, 300, 14, 7, 420, 190, 8, 9]


def partition(low, high):
    lo = low
    hi = high
    pivot = arr[lo]
    while lo < hi:
        while arr[lo] <= pivot:
            lo += 1
        while arr[hi] > pivot:
            hi -= 1
        if hi > lo:
            arr[lo], arr[hi] = arr[hi], arr[lo]
    arr[0], arr[hi] = arr[hi], arr[0]
    return hi


def quicksort(l, h):
    if l < h:
        j = partition(l, h)
        quicksort(l, j)
        quicksort(j + 1, h)


quicksort(0, 12)
print(arr)
```

P.S.: I'm a beginner (only 2 months of python) so please try to explain simply.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: _I just was told it must be used_ Perhaps you could ask the person who told you.

Comment: I doubt very much that your _partition_ function works correctly.

Comment: just remove it and test your algorithm.    If it has a purpose, a better choice than a constant 100000 would be `max(arr)+1` because it is clearly meant to be larger than any array element.

Comment: User1984.. it works i tested it on its own. The errors are all to do with the recirsion part

Comment: I removed the  inf  part still the same errors.

Comment: OK, on the input array you proposed, please run `partition(5, 12)` and check the results. On my end it looks buggy.

Comment: user1984...i ran it and i noticed that the indices 5-12 are sorted but with 81 as the pivot not 69 as it should be so looking at the code i see that the big mistake is line 15 which assumes that's the pivot is always arr[0] so I'm going to try and fix that and get back to you. Thank you.!

Comment: here's my new line 15: ` arr[low], arr[hi] = arr[hi], arr[low] ` and it runs fine with ` partition(5, 12) ` Still getting errors with my quicksort function tho

Comment: user1984...try running ` quicksort(0, 11) ` . It sorts the first 12 elements correctly but when u try ` quicksort(0, 12) ` it spits out errors. Weird

Comment: How do you justify the final swap in Partition ?

Comment: yves...because i have my pivot at the first index of the array i have to swap it with the point where ` hi ` and ` lo ` cross which is the point that has all numbers greater than the pivot to its right and all numbers smaller to its left so i swap pivot with ` hi ` cuz when ` hi ` crosses ` lo ` it has a value lower than the pivot so i put that value at the front and put the pivot in the middle so that the pivot is correctly sorted

Answer (score 1):

Your *partition* function is flawed. Also, you should make your functions more flexible/reusable by passing a reference to the list rather than working on a global variable. Here's my implementation using the Hoare algorithm and a different way to select the pivot:

```
def partition(A, lo, hi):
    pivot = A[(lo+hi)//2]
    i = lo - 1
    j = hi + 1
    while True:
        i += 1
        while A[i] < pivot:
            i += 1
        j -= 1
        while A[j] > pivot:
            j -= 1
        if i >= j:
            return j
        A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]


def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
    if lo < hi:
        p = partition(A, lo, hi)
        quicksort(A, lo, p)
        quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)


arr = [81, 4, 73, 1, 98, 69, 300, 14, 7, 420, 190, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 9]
quicksort(arr, 0, len(arr)-1)
print(arr)
```

Comment: I dont get whats the big difference between my partition and yours. Whats the flaw? Try running it.  Also, dumb question but does the return j statement make the program exit the infinite while loop?

Comment: Note how you have two "swaps" and yes, the *return* terminates the function returning the value of *j*. Try running my code